# What was the population of India in the age of Lord Krishna?

Tags: krishna, history, india

What was the population of India in the age of Lord Krishna? Was it still overcrowded like it is now? We all know its overpopulated now but was it the same previously?

Answer (score 3):

1/10th of population died in Mahabharata war, so you can calculate from there, there are 18 akshouhini sena 40 lac people killed in the war. 4 crore (4 - 5 crore) approx. 5115 years back

Comment: where did you get the 1/10th number ?

Comment: You should cite some sources to backup your answer.

Comment: Source Bannaje Govindacharya youtube video

Comment: youtube is not a source.